# How to make a custom NN layer in Mathematica?

Tags: customization, machine-learning, neural-networks

Is there a way to create our own custom layers for Neural Networks in Mathematica ? I suspect it should be possible, any pointers or directions on how to go about it?

I am interested in functionality like the "Lambda Layer" in Keras API.

Comment: I would love to see some docs on `NeuralNetworks\`DefineLayer`

Comment: Thats interesting ...

Comment: @swish Can you give a example that success to use it?

Comment: @yode Don't have one, that is the problem.

Comment: I am looking for a functionality that makes a layer can also let its weights be part of the output, so that one can use them to define a more sophisticated loss function, e.g., imposing constraints on the weights including but not limited to sum of absolute squares.

Comment: @AndyStowAway Isn't Keras' `Lambda` layer similar to _Mathematica_'s `ElementwiseLayer`?

Answer (score 16):

Supporting custom layers is on our to-do list, and should be ready for either 11.2 or 11.3.

For interest: what applications do you want custom layers for? And how performant do you need your custom layer to be? (for example, do you want to be able to write your own CUDA implementation? Or are you happy with writing your own CPU layer?)

Comment: Not a custom layer per se, but the ability to costomize weight sharing would be really useful.

Comment: Ok, could you give an explicit example?

Comment: @Sebastian Will you add stateful RNNs in the next releases? Option `Shuffle->(True|False)` for `NetTrain` is required. Also would be nice to add [Phased-LSTM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09513). "Phased LSTM extends the LSTM unit by adding a new time gate. This gate is controlled by a parametrized oscillation with a frequency range that produces updates of the memory cell only during a small percentage of the cycle. Phased LSTM network achieves faster convergence than regular LSTMs on tasks which require learning of long sequences."

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev: Mathematica is designed to be a functional language where things don't usually have state. Our network framework is built on the same principle. This means that we expose the RNN states explicitly as arguments (see the docs for LSTM etc). Its definitely annoying to use this for generation from RNN's. Expect major useability improvements for generation in 11.2. Also phased-lstm: will take a look. Can you implement it in 11.1 using `NetFoldOperator`?

Comment: @Sebastian I don't know how to implement using `NetFoldOperator`. I have created [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141185/how-to-implement-a-stateful-rnn).

Comment: @Sebastian An explicit examples of shares weight would be convolutional auto encoders where the decoder shares its weights with the Encoder (although transposed)

Comment: A simple layer I wish I could implement is a layer that randomly samples from its inputs in a [roulette wheel selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) scheme and outputs a corresponding one-hot encoded vector.

Comment: For example, spatial pyramidpooling(SPP), I hope Mathematica can use some costum layers to implement some recent papers' methods.

Comment: I definitely would be interested in custom layers, the ideal would be to wrap my own mxnet implementations. CUDA would be great, as it would allow to create RoiPooling / RoiAlign / SPP layers.

Comment: Sebastian, thanks for your response. I am using Mathematica 11.3 and am wondering if this functionality has been actually implemented. One reason to use it is to be able to take advantage of the rest of the system while investigating your own ideas in the NN area. By the way, thanks for the great article on O'Reilly!

Comment: @levK: I implemented a general custom-layer mechanism some months ago, but it turned out to cause many problems due to the asynchronous nature of the callbacks. For 12, a really good solution should exist though: custom layers via using the upcoming compiler infrastructure, with the end-game being direct compilation to CUDA! So stay tuned :-)

Comment: @Sebastian do you think i need to implement a custom layer to achieve the solution or are current capabilities in Mathematica enough to implement https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171769/how-to-use-catenatelayer-to-connect-nodes-within-a-netchain

Comment: @Sebastian did this ever happen?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a practical example using `` NeuralNetworks`DefineLayer ``: [ModelZoo/PGGAN-128 trained on Anime](https://github.com/GalAster/WLNet-ModelZoo/tree/master/ImageGeneration/Anime/PGGAN-128%20trained%20on%20Anime)

`PixelNorm.m` defines a new`PixelNormalizationLayer`:

```
Input: ChannelT[$$Channels, TensorT[$$InputDimensions]]
Output: ChannelT[$$Channels, TensorT[$$InputDimensions]]

Parameters:
    $Epsilon: Defaulting[ScalarT, 10^-8]
    $$Channels: SizeT
    $$InputDimensions: SizeListT[SizeT]

Writer: Function[
    input = GetInput["Input", "Batchwise"];
    path = SowNode["mean", SowSquare@input, "axis" -> 1, "keepdims" -> True];
    path = SowRSqrt@SowNode["_PlusScalar", path, "scalar" -> #Epsilon];
    output = SowNode["broadcast_mul", {input, path}];
    SetOutput["Output", output]
]

Suffix: "alizationLayer"
```

[image]

The executable notebook can be downloaded from [PGGAN-128.trained.on.Anime.zip](https://github.com/GalAster/WolframNeuralNetworks/releases/download/v0.3.1/PGGAN-128.trained.on.Anime.zip)

Every time you load the network, you must first load the custom layers through `` NeuralNetworks`DefineLayer ``.

Such a network cannot be submitted to NeuralNetRepository, and currently there is no solution similar to FunctionRepository.

---

You can see that the custom layer uses a domain-specific language

All options can be viewed by `` NeuralNetworks`Private`DefineLayer`LayerDefinitionT[[1, All, 1]] ``

There also contains type and interface information.

---

These options have their own roles, but there are only two necessary parts of a layer: `Input/Output` and `Writer`.

If you don't want to check the input and output, you can directly set it to `AnyTensorT`, which will not do any shape check.

`Writer` can specify how to convert to sow node.

`Sow` is a number of predefined operators.You can view all definitions via `` ? NeuralNetworks`Private`Sow* ``.

If it is not defined then the mxnet operator can be called directly through `SowNode`, All optional items can be viewed by `` ?MXNet` * ``.

Answer (score 9):

There are some documents written in markdown, under the path *SystemFiles\Components\NeuralNetworks*. Those under *Layers* are particularly of interest to question in OP.

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory
       , "SystemFiles", "Components", "NeuralNetworks"
       }] // FileNames["*.md", #, ∞] &

(*
SystemFiles\Components\NeuralNetworks\Encoders\EncoderFunctionAPI.md
                         .  .  .     \Layers\LayerDefinitions.md
                         .  .  .     \Layers\ShapePolymorphism.md
                         .  .  .     \Layers\Writers.md
                         .  .  .     \MXNet\Evaluation.md
                         .  .  .     \NetTrain.m\InternalOptions.md
                         .  .  .     \NetTrain.m\Overview.md
                         .  .  .     \Organization.md
*)
```

Comment: Too bad that those source code are no longer accessible in 12.3.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Mine are still there, under `.....\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\NeuralNetworks-12.0.11`. There are multiple versions of `NeuralNetworks` paclets in that folder.

Comment: I only see a `NeuralNetworks.mx` file in that folder, the same as that in the `SystemFiles\Components\NeuralNetworks` folder.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my guess for how to call `DefineLayer` based on the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) and some minimal spelunking.

First we define an `Association` defining the layer à la `` NeuralNetworks`$LayerData `` (seems that you need to drop `{"Symbol", "Type"}` based on how I was calling it):

```
fakeAssoc=
 KeyDrop[ NeuralNetworks`$LayerData["Linear"], {"Symbol", "Type"}]
```

Then just give it a name as a `String`:

```
NeuralNetworks`DefineLayer["Fake", fakeAssoc];
```

Now `` NeuralNetworks`FakeLayer `` is defined:

```
NeuralNetworks`FakeLayer[{}]
```

[image: fake layer]

If we want a non `` "NeuralNetworks`" `` level symbol instead, we'd need to make sure the [`` NameQ["System`"<>name] ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NameQ.html) is `True:

```
System`FakeLayer;
NeuralNetworks`DefineLayer["Fake",
  KeyDrop[ NeuralNetworks`$LayerData["Linear"], {"Symbol", "Type"}]
  ];

FakeLayer[{}]
```

[image: fake 2]

I think `` NeuralNetworks`$LayerData["Linear"] `` should be clear enough as a template for doing this. The parameter names seem pretty straight-forward:

```
NeuralNetworks`$LayerData["Linear"] // Keys

{"Inputs", "Outputs", "States", "Arrays", "Parameters", \
"ParameterCoercions", "ParameterDefaults", "InferenceRules", \
"RuntimeInferenceRules", "ShapeFunction", "RankFunction", \
"ExtraShapeFunctionTensors", "PostInferenceFunction", \
"PostConstructionFunction", "AuxArrays", "Writer", "Upgraders", \
"MXNet", "SubNets", "IsLoss", "IsOperator", "IsMultiport", \
"InheritsFrom", "Suffix", "SummaryFunction", "Tests", \
"AllowDynamicDimensions", "ReshapeParams", "ArgumentRewriter", \
"CUDNNArray", "Constraints", "StateExpanding", "MaxArgCount", \
"MinArgCount", "PosArgCount", "PosArgs", "SourceFile", "Type", \
"Symbol"}
```