# how to use CatenateLayer to connect nodes within a NetChain

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

**EDIT:
Looking closely at my network I have a similar problem of providing inputs to the CropLayer function. The output from the pooling layer (node 30) and node 87 (activation) should feed to the CropLayer. The question is how to feed outputs from one layer to other layers in the network**

I am trying to implement UNET (https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) in Mathematica.

I have the following code so far for generating the net partially:

(* encoder *)

```
encoder = NetEncoder[{"Image", "ImageSize" -> {168, 168}, "ColorSpace" -> "Grayscale"}];
```

(* decoder *)

```
decoder = NetDecoder[{"Image", "ColorSpace" -> Automatic}];
```

(* convolution module *)

```
Options[convolutionModule] = {"batchNorm" -> True, "downpool" -> False,
"uppool" -> False, "activationType" -> Ramp, "convolution" -> True};

convolutionModule[net_, kernelsize_, padsize_, stride_: {1, 1}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
With[{upPool = OptionValue["uppool"], activationType = OptionValue["activationType"], 
convolution = OptionValue["convolution"], batchNorm = OptionValue["batchNorm"],
downpool = OptionValue@"downpool"},

Block[{nnet = net},
If[upPool,
nnet = NetAppend[nnet, DeconvolutionLayer[1, {2, 2}, "PaddingSize" -> {0, 0}, 
   "Stride" -> {2, 2}]];
nnet = NetAppend[nnet, BatchNormalizationLayer[]];
If[activationType === Ramp,
 nnet = NetAppend[nnet, ElementwiseLayer[activationType]]
 ];
];
If[convolution,
 nnet = NetAppend[nnet, ConvolutionLayer[1, kernelsize, "Stride" -> stride,
   "PaddingSize" -> padsize]]
];
If[batchNorm,
nnet = NetAppend[nnet, BatchNormalizationLayer[]]
];
If[activationType === Ramp,
nnet = NetAppend[nnet, ElementwiseLayer[activationType]]
];
If[downpool,
nnet = NetAppend[nnet, PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Function" -> Max, "Stride" -> {2, 2}]]
];
nnet]
]
```

(* Crop Layer *)

```
CropLayer[netlayer_] := With[{p = NetExtract[netlayer, "Output"]},
PartLayer[{First@p, 1 ;; p[[2]], 1 ;; Last@p}] ];
```

(* UNET *)

```
UNET[] := 
Block[{nm, pool1, pool2, pool3, pool4, pool5, kernelsize = {3, 3}, 
padsize = {1, 1}, stride = {1, 1}},
nm = NetChain@
Join[{ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, 
   "Input" -> encoder]}, {BatchNormalizationLayer[], 
  ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
  PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Function" -> Max, "Stride" -> {2, 2}]}];
pool1 = nm[[-1]];
nm = convolutionModule[nm, kernelsize, padsize, stride,"downpool" -> True];
pool2 = nm[[-1]];
nm = convolutionModule[nm, kernelsize, padsize, stride,"downpool" -> True];
pool3 = nm[[-1]];
nm = convolutionModule[nm, kernelsize, padsize, stride,"downpool" -> True];
pool4 = nm[[-1]];
nm = NetAppend[nm, DropoutLayer[]];
nm = convolutionModule[nm, kernelsize, padsize, stride, "downpool" -> True];
pool5 = nm[[-1]];
nm = convolutionModule[nm, kernelsize, padsize, stride, "uppool" -> True]; 
nm = convolutionModule[nm, kernelsize, padsize + 1, stride, "uppool" -> True]; 
nm = NetAppend[nm, CropLayer@pool3];
```

with `NetInformation` I can generate the net plot below:

`NetInformation[(nm = UNET[]), "MXNetNodeGraphPlot"]`

[image]

My problem is: how do i **catenate** the output from the `pooling layer` i.e. node 30 with the output from node 91.

I tried using `NetGraph` with `CatenateLayer` but could not find a way to connect node 30 within the NetChain with the second input of `CatenateLayer`.

[image]

Comment: Please try to reduce this to a minimal working example.

Comment: @MarcoB will do later in the day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**U-Net**

```
conv[n_] := NetChain[
  {
   ConvolutionLayer[n, 3, "PaddingSize" -> {1, 1}],
   Ramp,
   BatchNormalizationLayer[],
   ConvolutionLayer[n, 3, "PaddingSize" -> {1, 1}],
   Ramp,
   BatchNormalizationLayer[]
   }
  ]

pool := PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, 2]

dec[n_] := NetGraph[
  {
   "deconv" -> DeconvolutionLayer[n, {2, 2}, "Stride" -> {2, 2}],
   "cat" -> CatenateLayer[],
   "conv" -> conv[n]
   },
  {
   NetPort["Input1"] -> "cat",
   NetPort["Input2"] -> "deconv" -> "cat" -> "conv"
   }
  ]


unet = NetGraph[
   <|
    "enc_1" -> conv[64],
    "enc_2" -> {pool, conv[128]},
    "enc_3" -> {pool, conv[256]},
    "enc_4" -> {pool, conv[512]},
    "enc_5" -> {pool, conv[1024]},
    "dec_1" -> dec[512],
    "dec_2" -> dec[256],
    "dec_3" -> dec[128],
    "dec_4" -> dec[64],
    "map" -> {ConvolutionLayer[1, {1, 1}], LogisticSigmoid}
    |>,
   {
    NetPort["Input"] -> "enc_1" -> "enc_2" -> "enc_3" -> "enc_4" -> "enc_5",
    {"enc_4", "enc_5"} -> "dec_1",
    {"enc_3", "dec_1"} -> "dec_2",
    {"enc_2", "dec_2"} -> "dec_3",
    {"enc_1", "dec_3"} -> "dec_4",
    "dec_4" -> "map"
    },
   "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {512, 512}, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"}]
   ] // NetInitialize
```

[image]

```
img = RandomImage[1, {512, 512}];

unet@img
```

[image]

Comment: @AliHashmi Look how I defined decoder (with `CatenateLayer` in it) and connected it with other layers inside of `NetGraph`.

Comment: Many thanks. upvoted it. Will check your implementation thoroughly at night. I will accept the answer after a couple of days :)

Comment: can we create a room and talk there? I have a few questions in mind if you can kindly help.

Comment: @AliHashmi My email: `alexey.golyshev@live.com`. Write your questions.

Comment: kindly check the following question i have posted if it interests you? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172481/how-can-image-segmentation-from-unet-be-improved